# How can I send a command to the ESP32S Bluetooth module with the mobile application and get the response?

Tags: java, esp32, android-bluetooth

I researched a lot of libraries and sample applications on the internet. But none of them worked because they were up to date. I'm still new to Java. There are two sample source codes below.

- [First Example Project](https://github.com/omaraflak/Bluetooth-Library/tree/master)
- [Second Example Project](https://github.com/The-Frugal-Engineer/ArduinoBTExamplev3/tree/main)

The problem I had with the first one was;

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 17.0.6 and Gradle 5.6.4.

Possible solution:
 - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 7.2 version and re-import the project
```

When I change the Gradle version, I get different errors. I could not find a solution to these errors.

The problem I had with the second one is this: While creating a connection to the bluetooth module within the project, it connected with the UUID. But since ESP32S does not have a UUID, I cannot connect. I have no idea how to fix this.